# VBA ByRef Error Passing a Class Object to a Sub

Tags: vba, class, mismatch, byref

I'm trying to pass an object to a new sub but keep hitting a ByRef Mismatch error.

I've declared my object as:

```
Dim targetWorkbook
Set targetWorkbook = New CWorkbooks
```

I'm calling my sub by using:

```
checkbook targetWorkbook
```

And my sub is set as:

```
Sub checkbook(targetWorkbook As CWorkbooks)

'Checking if passthrough is working

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated, my types are aligned and everything so I'm not sure why this is occuring.

Thanks!

Comment: `TargetWorkbook` needs to be declared at the module level, else it will be out of scope in `checkbook`. It doesn't look like you are setting it at the module level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your problem with the compiler. The following passes the compiler and runs. You declared `TargetWorkbook` as Variant, then set it to CWorkbooks - this works, but not when passed to the sub.

```
Sub main()
    Dim TargetWorkbook As CWorkbooks
    Set TargetWorkbook = New CWorkbooks
    checkbook TargetWorkbook
End Sub
Sub checkbook(ByRef TargetWorkbook As CWorkbooks)

'Checking if passthrough is working

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Foo()
    'single class object
    Dim myClass1 As New clsClass
    myClass1.StringName = "cls1"
    Call Par(myClass1)

    'or class array
    Dim myClass2(1 To 5) As New clsClass
    myClass2(1).StringName = "cls2"
    Call Par(myClass2)

End Sub

Sub Par(ByRef lClass As Variant) 'same function call used for both
    'Debug.Print lClass.StaffName & vbNewLine 'single class object
    'Debug.Print lClass(1).StaffName & vbNewLine 'array version
End Sub
```

google brought me here for same problem but found the accepted answer lacking & didn't work at all in my case where Foo() was a module & Par() a worksheet, trying to pass class array.